# Getopts perl order

Tags: perl, getopts

I am having some problems with getopts in perl.

I use:

```
getopts("abc:ds:", \%options);
```

and I'm cheking the options with

```
if (defined $options{a})
```

where $options is the hash the options are written into.

After the options the user has to enter a file name, that I locate with $ARGV[0]. The problem is, that the user can not put the options after the file name, but only before.

So this is working:

```
skript.pl -a file.txt
```

And this is not working:

```
skript.pl file.txt -a
```

How can I escape this problem?

Thank you!

-Alex

Answer (score 4):

Getopt::Std is really too limited to use in almost every case.

Use Getopt::Long and set the permute option to allow this.